# Proof of Lemma 3 in TRPO

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am currently working on the Trust Region policy optimization topic (https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.05477). In particular, i try to understand the proof of the main theorem and am currently working on lemma 3.

There is one step where i really doubt the correctness.
The main setting is as follows:

We consider two policies $\pi (s,a) = P (A_t =a \mid S_t =s)$ and $\tilde \pi (s,a) = P (\tilde A_t =a \mid S_t =s)$ and assume that there is a joint distribution $P (A_t =a, \tilde A_t = \tilde a \mid S_t =s)$ and that $P(A_t \neq A_t \mid S_t = s) \leq \alpha$.

Then the random variable $N_t$ is introduced which is defined as
$$
N_t = |\{i\in \{0, \dots, t-1\}: A_i \neq \tilde A_i\}|.
$$
So it counts how often the two policies generate different action. Now we want to bound $P(N_t = 0)$ from below using our assumption.

The proof states now:
" By defintion of $\alpha$, $P(\pi, \tilde \pi \text{ agree at timestep }i) \geq 1- \alpha$, so $P(n_t = 0) \geq (1- \alpha)^t$, "

As I understand the proof, the authors assume $P(A_t \neq \tilde A_t) \leq \alpha$ and that events $A_t \neq \tilde A_t$ and $A_d \neq \tilde A_d$ are independent for $t \neq d$.
Why can we drop the condition $S_t = s$ ? And why are those events independent ?

I hope someone can enlighten me. I know it is a very specific question, but maybe anyone has already worked through the proof.

Comment: *"And why are those events independent?"* This is an **assumption**. Without it the lemma would not be right. For instance we could have a dependent situation where $a_i = \tilde a_i$ becomes more probable for some time $i$ if it is not at other times. This would make $n_t = 0$ less probable and $P(n_t = 0)$ potentially smaller than $(1-\alpha)^t$

Comment: The condition $S_t = s$ is difficult to speak about. It is in the question not clear what it is. I quickly looked at the article, but it is not easy to dive into directly at the end.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is just the law of total probability;
\begin{align}
\Pr(A_t \neq \tilde A_t)
= \int \Pr(A_t \neq \tilde A_t \mid S_t = s) \Pr(S_t = s) \mathrm d s
\leq \alpha \int \Pr(S_t = s) \mathrm d s
= \alpha
\end{align}